# Datagridview with variable columns how?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im new to C# and want to use a datagridview where the two first colums is the same every time and the rest i dependent of the content of a string list. But how can i do that ?

My code looks like this right now and i can see the failure, but dont know what to do about it :(

Plz help me :)

```
        View.Columns.Clear();
        View.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colTime = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colTime.DataPropertyName = "Time";
        colTime.HeaderText = "Time";
        colTime.Name = "Time";
        colTime.Width = 55;
        View.Columns.Add(colTime);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colPlace = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colPlace.DataPropertyName = "Place";
        colPlace.HeaderText = "Place";
        colPlace.Name = "Place";
        colPlace.Width = 55;
        View.Columns.Add(colPlace);


        for(int i = 0; i < Liste.Length; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn "Log"+List[i] = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            "Log"+List[i].DataPropertyName = "List[i]";
            "Log"+List[i].HeaderText = "List[i]";
            "Log"+List[i].Name = "List[i]";
            "Log"+List[i].Width = 55;
            View.Columns.Add("Log"+List[i]);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want JUST create datagridview dynamically??? and then, you can set Col1 and Col2 as same every time.

Comment: Yes i want to create the col 3 - x dynamically. When the program i startede it is not know hvor many col´s there is needed. Then i want to load a list of strings that should be the name of col 3 - x.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function for creating typical `DataGridView` automatically,

```
DataGridView CreateDataGridDynamically(int NumberOfCol)
{
    DataGridView D = new DataGridView();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCol; i++)
    {

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn C1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        C1.HeaderText = "Something";
        D.Columns.Add(C1);
    }
    return D;
}
```

and with datagridview.Rows.Add() and the forth overload, you can simply add some rows with your constraint:

```
DataGridView D = CreateDataGridDynamically(3);
D.Rows.Add("Sth1", "Sth1", "Sth3");
D.Rows.Add("Sth1", "Sth1", "Sth3");
D.Rows.Add("Sth1", "Sth1", "Sth3");
Controls.Add(D);
```